# Checking if a value has been in the user class has been created Parse Server Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, heroku, parse-server

In a project I am working on the user goes through a sing up process. In the process a user is created using their entered username and password, if that succeeds then a fullName, and accountVerified is added to the current user with its corresponding value.

The problem is if the user quits the application before the save is complete then the image, fullName, and accountVerified is not added to the current user.

This causes a problem later when the application is relaunched. When the app is relaunched it checks for a user, if there is a user then it checks of if their accountVerified value is true or false. Since the user quit before the save completed there is no accountVerified to check as acountVerified and its value were not added to the user.

To account for this I will save the users fullName, and accountVerified to NSUserDefaults and when the app is launched check if those are created and given a value. If not then use the NSUserDefault values will be used to set the values and save to the current user.

The Question:

I use Parse Server with Heroku and mLab mongoDB. I am wondering what the best way to check the current users object to see if accountVerified, and fullName have been created. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Query user with 'where' accuntVerified = True; set1   Query user with 'where' accountVerified = False; set2    If the user does not exist in set1 or set2, accountverified is not set.

Comment: So if the user does not exist in set1 or set2 would that mean that acountVerified hasn't been created or just that its value is not defined? Thanks!

Comment: When a class has a variable that is not assigned a value explicitly, it is set to undefined. So it will not be true or false. All class members are created with value undefined by default. You can see this in the Parse dashboard.

Comment: Correct but the variable is not created if the user quits before the save is complete so I can't check if the variable is even undefined as it doesn't exist.

Comment: Any class you create on Parse, needs a schema. Add a column named accountVerfified with boolean type. All the values start undefined unless explicitly set by a user. So event if a user aborts out, it will have undefined as value which will make it fall outside set 1 or 2.